# Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK dosn't work fine - ANDROID

Tags: java, android, calendar, dayofweek

i'm developing an Application which need to get the current Day of Week and the current time to change an Integer depending on the day and the date.

I have made this but I have few problems:
It freezes on Tuesday midday.
It gives me this::

```
Unexpected constant; 
expected one of: Calendar.FRIDAY, Calendar.MONDAY, Calendar.SATURDAY, Calendar.SUNDAY, Calendar.THURSDAY, Calendar.TUESDAY, Calendar.WEDNESDAY less...
This check warns if a switch statement does not explicitly include all the 
values declared by the typedef @IntDef declaration.
```

And I don't know how to fix it.

There is my code:
When I write this, It works except for Tuesday:

```
int countuser = 0;
                int day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                int timeOfDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

                switch (day) {
                    case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 0;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.MONDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 2;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 3;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 4;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 5;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 6;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 7;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 8;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 9;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 10;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 11;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 12;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 13;
                        }
                        break;
                }
```

But I would like to sort the countuser depending of the day so I made this but it freezes my app:

```
switch (day) {
                    case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 8;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 9;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.MONDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 0;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 10;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 11;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 12;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 13;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 6;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 7;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 2;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 3;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 4;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 5;
                        }
                        break;
                }
```

And same for this, when i try to sort the "case Calendar.MONDAY":

```
 switch (day) {
                    case Calendar.MONDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 0;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 2;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 3;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 4;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 5;
                        }
                        break;

                    case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 6;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 7;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 8;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 9;
                        }
                        break;

                    case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 10;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 11;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 12;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 13;
                        }


                }
```

So how can I do to get the current day of week and time to change the value of my Integer ? I tried a lot of thing but either it freezes or either it doesn't work for all the day...

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:**

Here is a list of my import:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
```

Comment: What is the exact error?  The `switch` statement on an integer looks like it should work to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The problem is I don't know the exact error, the only thing I know is that this code is in a BackgroundWorker AsyncTask and this Integer help me to sort an ArrayList depending to the day, but when i'm in the two last case, the backgroundWorker "crash" and the application freeze and don't give me any error, but it didn't work because the backgroundWorker can't do the onPostExecute.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But as I said in the post, the switch statement said an Unexpected constant so I don't know if this is the cause

Comment: See it looks, there are flaws in your code, like (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) is true all integer values. I don't know your exact error, or if this is intended.

Comment: Do you have a runtime error or is this a build problem?

Comment: The problem is that i don't have any error, It just stops doing the code after this part, if i remove the switch statement the code works well but with it stop doing the rest of the code and 1-2 minutes after it says : App doesn't respond @TimBiegeleisen And I fixed the flaws so it wasn't cause of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but could you post your imports? And try putting this inside an try-catch block.

EDIT:

A try-catch block will *try* to *catch* an exception that could be thrown by your code.

```
    try {
        switch (day) {
                    case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 0;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.MONDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 2;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 3;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 4;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 5;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 6;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 7;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 8;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 9;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 10;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 11;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                        if (timeOfDay > 22 || timeOfDay < 16) {
                            countuser = 12;
                        } else if (timeOfDay >= 16 || timeOfDay <= 22) {
                            countuser = 13;
                        }
                        break;
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I put my import in the main post. And I don't exactly know how to put it inside an try-catch block, can you help me ?

Comment: Edited my answer. The code runs perfectly on my system without this though; I hope you've tried the clean-rebuild thing.

Comment: It worked with rebuilded... I'm so sorry but thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem @MelvinAuvray (: